# Some remarks on JCF which I want to get verified

Tags: linear-algebra

- *Jordan Cannonical Form* is applicable for all the linear operators whose characteristic polynomial factors linearly over the base field.

> **Jordan Cannonical Form:** Let $T:V_F\to V_F~(\dim V_F<\infty)$ be a linear operator such that $\chi_T(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k (x-\lambda_i)^{n_i}$ where $n_i\in\mathbb Z^+~\forall~i.$ Then $m_T(x)$ is of the form $m_T(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k(x-\lambda_i)^{m_i}$ where $m_i(\le n_i)\in\mathbb Z^+\cup\{0\}~\forall~i.$ Then $T$ has a block diagonal matrix representation where each block is *Jordan block* $J_{ij}$ belonging to some $\lambda_i~(i=1,2,...,k)$ i.e. $J_{ij}=J(\lambda_i)$ so that the followings get satisfied: $(1)$ Order of at least one $J(\lambda_i)$ is $m_i$ and the rest $\le m_i;(2)$ total no of $J(\lambda_i)=$ geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_i;(3)$ Sum of the orders of all $J(\lambda_i)=n_i;(4)$ the no of $J(\lambda_i)$ of order $p\le m_i$ remains the same for each *such* (where 1-3 get satisfied ) Jordan block diagonal representation of $T.$

**Remarks:** We put aside the case that $V=(0)$ for which $T$ is the null matrix, by default.

1. $\lambda_i$ is not a root of $m_T(x)\implies m_i=0\implies$ each $J(\lambda_i)$ is of order  $0$ whence $J(\lambda_i)$ doesn't exist in JCF. (though it never happens!)
2. no of $J(\lambda_i)=\dim E_T(\lambda_i)$ and order of $J(\lambda_i)\le m_i\implies~\sum $ orders of $J(\lambda_i)$$\le m_i\times \dim E_T(\lambda_i)\implies m_i\le n_i\le m_i\times \dim E_T(\lambda_i).$

   - In part. $m_i=0$$\implies n_i=0!$ so $m_i>0~\forall~i=1,2,...,k.$ Consequently $\lambda_i$ is a root of the characteristic equation implies there is a $J(\lambda_i)$ in the JCF of nonzero order.
3. If $T:V^n\to V^n$ is nilpotent of index $k\ge0$ i.e. $\chi_T(x)=x^n$ and $m_T(x)=x^k~(1\le k\le n)$ then there's only one *type of* Jordan block viz. $J(0).$ But $J(0)=N$ i.e. the Jordan nilpotent matrix.

   - there's one $N$ in the JCF of order $k,$ all other $N$ are of order $\le k.$ (In part if $k=1(\iff T=0)$ then the JCF is the zero matrix)
   - the no of $N$ in the JCF is $\dim E_T(0)=\ker T$
   - the sum of the orders of all $J(0)=n$
   - the order of each $N$ is uniquely determined by $T$
   - $k\le n\le k\times\ker T$

Comment: Could you make it clear in the content of your question what it is you are asking (I know the title says you want your remarks verified, but questions should be self-contained)? Also, you missed a dollar sign at the end of the quote.

Comment: What is the question here? Perhaps you should focus more, and in at least two different parts you talk of the case $\,m_i=0,\,$ , which is tantamount to $\,\lambda_i\,$ is *not* an eigenvalue...this is pretty boring and trivial, isn't it? I'm not saying it sholdn't be considered...but almost: a quick check of this boring case and let us continue with the real interesting stuff.